# How to Run Server Exe File From Client Pc

Tags: vb.net

I am put 2-3 VB.net application into server share folder.
Then i create an VB application that contain 3 button that click link to specific vb.net application.

Example :
Main UI > 3 Buttons (1,2,3) > 
Click Button 1 Link to Application 1,
Click Button 2 Link to Application 2,and 
Click Button 3 Link to Application 3 .

So that user can open this main UI to choose what they want to use.
The problem i faced is The path problem:

Example :

```
    Process.Start("D:\APPlication\APP1.exe")
```

This path will run only local pc but not server. What i can do ?
Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the shared folder address like the users will see.
They usually start with "\\"